# how to upload to remote folder saved audio from html5 getusermedia microphone

Tags: html, getusermedia

I have this file thats created with html5, I am just starting to learn.
Basically when I am recording from the microphone and stop the record I am finding it hard to upload the outputted file to a folder on the server.

Here is the page i am testing on.

http://2click4.com/playground.php

Comment: Could you add some example code of what your attempting to do? I would suggest adding the 'S' logic in your page to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `Blob` and `createObjectURL` in your code on example page. You create `ObjectURL`, so you can send it by `XMLHttpRequest` to server:

```
var blob = new Blob ( [ view ], { type : 'audio/wav' } );
// let's save it locally
outputElement.innerHTML = 'Handing off the file now...';
var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'link_to_server', true);
xhr.onload = function (e) {
    var result = e.target.result;
};
xhr.send(url);//url is Blob
```

Comment: view the source code now i added 

var blob = new Blob ( [ view ], { type : 'audio/wav' } );
        
        // let's save it locally
       
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://www.2click4.com/mods/msg', true);
xhr.onload = function (e) {
    var result = e.target.result;
};
xhr.send('http://www.2click4.com/mods/msg');

Comment: `xhr.send(url)` url is `Blob`. Not String.

Comment: You a set the String `2click4.com/mods/msg` instead of `Blob` variable `url` in to `send` method.

Comment: could you please complete the code, i am having a very hard time understanding the answer you have provided, i have changed the blob variable to send url

Comment: whats xhr.open('POST', 'link_to_server', true);
is 'link_to_server' the folder im storing the .wav in or do i need a .php page to store the wav in